# Will Google Drive perform OCR on existing (badly) OCRed PDFs?

Tags: pdf, google-drive, ocr

I use ScanSnap's software to perform OCR on scanned PDFs, then realized the OCR contains a lot of errors and I couldn't find a lot of information in search.
So I tried some scans without OCR, uploaded to Google Drive and it recognized the text correctly. HOWEVER, I tried to uploaded the already-OCRed PDFs and Google Drive doesn't seem to be performing OCR on them, because I can't find the words during search.

Can anyone confirm if Google Drive won't OCR an already-OCRed PDF, or is it just taking a long time to index the contents in my case? And furthermore, how do I batch-remove the badly OCRed information from a bunch of PDFs?

Comment: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/176692 this seems to detail how to open PDF in Google Docs which extracts just the text, so it's embedding it into the PDF which is what I think you are talking about?

Comment: I can perform OCR on a PDF, but if the PDF has already been OCRed offline before being uploaded to Google Drive, then Google Drive doesn't seem to do anything with it.

Comment: You could run `cpdf -remove-all-text in.pdf -o out.pdf` (disclaimer, I wrote it) to remove all the OCRd text, leaving just the scanned images. Google Drive will presumably then choose to OCR it for search purposes.